# Weird behavior of strip()

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> adf = "123 ABCD#"
>>> df = "<ABCD#>" 
>>> adf.strip(df)
>>> '123 '
>>> xc = "dfdfd ABCD#!"
>>> xc.strip(df)
>>> 'dfdfd ABCD#!'
```

Why does strip() take out ABCD# in adf? 
Does strip completely ignore "<" and ">" ?Why does it remove the chars when no "<" and ">" are there in the original string?

Comment: why does it matter?

Comment: Consider `'www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.<>')` The characters used to strip are a set; any characters on both ends of the string are removed until they cannot be removed.

Comment: Would it kill people to read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) before asking questions that are so trivially answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method strip() returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning and the end of the string (default whitespace characters).

The characters that are in df, they occur at the end in the string adf. This is not the case in string xc where the first and last character are ! and d.

str.strip([chars]); => If any character in str occurs in chars at last or first index, then that character is stripped off from str. Then it again checks. When no character is stripped, it stops.

Comment: does it ignore "<" and ">" part of df?

Comment: Since string adf did not contain "<" or ">" so it ignores them in this case.

Comment: thanks, in other words, strip() looks for individual char in [chars] and remove them from front and end of the string? correct?

Comment: Absolutely. If anyone of the char in [chars] occurs, it strips them off

Comment: @user3837980 so each **individual** char in `chars` is the catch.

Comment: Yes. And also it keeps on stripping until it can no longer strip a character from the string. Then the function returns